# Dovecot Component that handles connection and passing data among its processes

Tags: dovecot

I am looking for the component that interacts with the email client and passes credential for further authentication within Dovecot.

I am also looking for the component that passes from the mail process to the email client.

Comment: I am also referring the component that manages the connection between the client and the mailbox server.